# Any way in Groovy/Java to identify the subclass calling a static method?

Tags: java, groovy, subclass, static-methods, abstract

Groovy is so powerful I wonder whether there's an easy way to do this.

The scenario:

I have an abstract class, `AbstractSequence`. Then I have two (more in reality) subclasses, called say `CasedSequence` and `LowerCaseSequence`.  Each of these concrete classes has to have an "identity map", i.e. like a `Set` but where it is possible to extract an element based on functional equality (overriding of `equals` and `hashCode`).

So we have:

```
class CasedSequence extends AbstractSequence {
    static Map identityMap = [:]
...

class LowerCaseSequence extends AbstractSequence {
    static Map identityMap = [:]
```

In fact, for reasons that would take too long to explain, manipulation of these identity maps in the respective classes also uses lots of static methods, all similar/identical from one subclass to the other. So I wondered how one might refactor to put the identity maps in the abstract base class (and then migrate a lot of the repetitive static methods there).

This led me to this:

```
abstract class AbstractSequence {

    static Map getIdentityMap( Class clazz ) {
        if( ! ( clazz in identityMaps )) 
            identityMaps[ clazz ] = [ : ]
        identityMaps[ clazz ]
    }
    static Map identityMaps = [:]
```

and then in the concrete classes, each time you want to use the identity map you have to do this:

```
class CasedSequence extends AbstractSequence {
    def someMethod( CasedSequence seq1 ){
        CasedSequence seq2 = getIdentityMap( CasedSequence )[ seq1 ] 
...
```

Again, it's too complicated to explain why you need to retrieve things this way... but I'm just wondering whether there's a way (an elegant Groovy way?) in `AbstractSequence.getIdentityMap()` to identify the class of the subclass calling `getIdentityMap()`, rather than having to pass this class as a parameter?

PS I'd rather not use `Thread.stackTrace`: it's cumbersome and won't deliver the actual class object, only the class name, and also stack traces in Groovy are wild. I'm thinking more in terms of Groovy reflection, Groovy metaclasses...

Comment: *"In fact, for reasons that would take too long to explain, manipulation of these identity maps in the respective classes also uses lots of static methods, all similar/identical from one subclass to the other. "* ... the Java/Groovy way of handling something like this would be do define your API in an interface, in this case very likely generic, then write as much of a skeletal implementation in an abstract class, do away with the static methods altogether, and `@Override` the `getIdentityMap()` method in each of the concrete subclasses.  You can pass *type tokens* to identify subclasses.

Comment: "Do away with the static methods altogether".  Can you accept it when I say that just can't be done? Possibly it could be achieved with some "managing" auxiliary class... but that would also be pretty complicated.

Comment: why wouldn't you just use a non-static `getIdentityMap()` method which calls static `getIdentityMap(getClass())`?

Comment: @jtahlborn in fact you usually need to obtain this identity map in a static context, so there is no object on which to call `getIdentityMap()`.

Comment: if you are obtaining this identity map in a static context, then you have no class type...  this doesn't make any sense?

Comment: I think I understand: are you saying that by its nature a call from a static method cannot reveal the class to which it belongs?

Comment: a static method knows which class it is in, it is the class the definition was written within.  if you are talking about potentially multiple layers of static method calls, then this is a more complicated problem.  i think you need to give a better example in your question.  my suggestion would work for your current example of `someMethod()`.

Comment: Right. So when there is a call to static method X (a static method in a superclass) in a static context (static method Y) in a subclass, is there any way for X to identify the class containing Y?

Comment: no, not without explicitly passing the identity of Y through the various method calls.  i assume there are "too many" method calls that you don't want to just write this as an explicit method call argument?

Comment: *"Can you accept it when I say that just can't be done? Possibly it could be achieved with some "managing" auxiliary class.."* ... I don't know your problem domain, so I'll take your word for it.  But in my experience, a system that solves a problem with many static fields and methods is likely to be one that could have been solved better with a more object-oriented approach.  If I have a class that other classes must know stuff about, I've written a metadata interface for it and instantiated that at load time.  It's not wrong to think of `Class<T>` as a metadata object for `T`, for example.

Comment: @scottb Yes, too much use of static fields and methods also feels wrong to me. I'm not clever enough to get a clear idea of what you mean by your suggestion: do you have a concrete example I could link to?  Or maybe you could outline the bare bones in an answer to this question???

Answer (score 0):

Would be interested in hearing from any Groovy gurus about this.

In the mean time I have used a bit of Groovy magic for a workaround, taking advantage of the fact that the Groovy GDK adds some methods to the `class` class, one being `newInstance()` - pretty useful.  This "makes or gets" a sequence object depending on whether or not the sought sequence is already in the identity map.

```
    static makeOrGet( String string, Class clazz ) {
        def dummySeq = clazz.newInstance( DUMMY_STRING )
        // NB the constructor identifies the string DUMMY_STRING to prevent this new object being 
        // properly "registered" (i.e. put in the identity map), which would be wrong because 
        // the dummy seq is just to find out whether the sequence with "string" is actually 
        // present in the map

        def seq
        // disguise the dummy sequence to flush out an existing sequence with String "string"
        dummySeq.string = string
        if( dummySeq in getIdentityMap( clazz ) )
            seq = getIdentityMap( clazz )[ dummySeq ]
        else
            // NB constructor puts the new "clazz" object in the identity map
            seq = clazz.newInstance( string )
        seq
    }
```

... so the above method can be called with various different classes as parameter 2 and then delivers an object of class `clazz`, either extracted from the identity map or constructed (and put in the map).